# (SQL HELP) Can Some Please Tell Me Where I Am Going Wrong With This?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am a first year student and I am studying for a Computing degree. I have been undertaking a module based on designing and building a databse.

Below is the database that I have created and this is based on the casestudy that was issued. I have tried to use validators etc with no luck.

When I try to execute this code I am getting a lot of syntax errors, please help I have failed to come up with a solution.

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (

      PRIMARY KEY  (`STUDENT_ID`),
      UNIQUE KEY (`TENANT_ID`)

      `STUDENT_ID` INT (11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `TENANT_ID` INT (11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `NAME` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',
      `SURNAME` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',
      `DOB` DATETIME NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
      `ADDRESS` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',
      `POSTCODE` VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL default '',
      `EMAIL` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',
        `PHONE` VARCHAR (14) NOT NULL default '',
      `CONFIRMED` INT (1) NOT NULL default '0',
        `GENDER` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL CHECK (Gender IN ('M', 'F'))


    ) 

INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`01', '001', ‘GRASS’, ‘LIAM’, ‘20-JUL-1992’,‘M’,'5 BROWN LANE','SS8 4FG','lgrass@gmail.com', `07458914578', );
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`02', '002', ‘BONES’, ‘PAUL’, ‘01-OCT-1991’,‘M’,'112 SAND WAY','CM15 7GT','pbones@gmail.com', `07985214748', );
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`03', '003', ‘KOLINSKY’, ‘RAV’, ‘19-SEP-1991’,‘M’,'111 ROVER ROAD','ER44 4RT','rkoli@gmail.com', `07723698517', );
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`04', '004', ‘MKO’, ‘LUCY’, ‘02-DEC-1992’,‘F’,'4 PEM GROVE','E12 W34','mko@gmail.com', `07528963756', );
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`05', '005', ‘MAKAMA’, ‘JENNY’, ‘23-JAN-1991’,‘F’,'4445 GOGG LANE','WC1E 3ER','makama@gmail.com', `07985641577', );
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`06', '006', ‘RAKTA’, ‘RAUL’, ‘10-MAY-1991’,‘M’,'234 ELA ROAD','SS8 4FG','rrakta@gmail.com', `07854711147', );
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`07', '007', ‘KUELA’, ‘CARLORINA’, ‘15-JUN-1992’,‘F’,'234 GRAND ROAD','BD8 9RR','ckuela@gmail.com', `07444589214', );
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`08', '008', ‘GEORGE’, ‘BEST’, ‘18-OCT-1991’,‘M’,'4 RAIL ROAD','MM5 5NN','gbest@gmail.com', `07884710369', );
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`09', '010', ‘KNOW’, ‘WER’, ‘02-FEB-1992’,‘F’,'9 LANE LANE','BG74 8UH','wknow@gmail.com', `07474010502', );
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`10', '010', ‘FAN’, ‘FANWELL’, ‘10-NOV-1992’,‘M’,'2 GNOME ROAD','GF3 8VA','ffan@gmail.com', `07425800369', );

CREATE TABLE `accommodation` (

    PRIMARY KEY  (`ROOM_ID`)
    UNIQUE KEY (`HALLS_NAME`) 

    `ROOM_ID` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREAMENT,
    `TYPE` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',
    `PRICE` INT (11) NOT NULL default '0',
    `HALLS_NAME` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',
    `STATUS` INT (1) NOT NULL default '0',
    `TENANT_ID` INT (11) NOT NULL default '',
    `START_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `END_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0001`, `ENSUITE`, `400`, `FOX`, `OCCUPIED`, `001`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0002`, `SINGLE`, `200`, `FOX`, `OCCUPIED`, `002`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0003`, `SINGLE`, `200`, `FOX`, `OCCUPIED`, `003`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0004`, `DISABLED`, `600`, `FOX`, `OCCUPIED`, `004`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0001`, `SINGLE`, `300`, `CUB`, `OCCUPIED`, `005`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0002`, `SINGLE`, `300`, `CUB`, `VACANT`, ``, ``, ``,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0003`, `ENSUITE`, `500`, `CUB`, `OCCUPIED`, `006`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0004`, `SINGLE`, `300`, `CUB`, `VACANT`, ``, ``, ``,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0001`, `ENSUITE`, `500`, `TIGER`, `OCCUPIED`, `007`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0002`, `ENSUITE`, `500`, `TIGER`, `OCCUPIED`, `008`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0003`, `ENSUITE`, `500`, `TIGER`, `VACANT`, ``, ``, ``,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0004`, `ENSUITE`, `500`, `TIGER`, `VACANT`, ``, ``, ``,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0001`, `SINGLE`, `200`, `LION`, `OCCUPIED`, `009`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0002`, `SINGLE`, `200`, `LION`, `OCCUPIED`, `010`, `01-OCT-2009`, `01-OCT-2010`,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0003`, `ENSUITE`, `500`, `LION`, `VACANT`, ``, ``, ``,);
  INSERT INTO `accommodation` VALUES (`0003`, `ENSUITE`, `500`, `LION`, `VACANT`, ``, ``, ``,);


  CREATE TABLE `staff` (

  PRIMARY KEY  (`EMPLOYEE_ID`)
  UNIQUE KEY (`EMAIL`)

      `EMPLOYEE_ID` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREAMENT,
      `SURNAME` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',
      `GENDER` INT (1) NOT NULL default 'M',
      `INSPECTS` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',
      `RECRUITED` INT (11) NOT NULL default '',
      `POSTCODE` VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL default '',      
      `DOB` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
      `POSITION` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',
      `SALARY` INT (11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `EMAIL` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',

    ) 

  DELIMITER //
  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS MAX_NUM//
  CREATE TRIGGER MAX_NUM BEFORE INSERT ON STAFF
  FOR EACH ROW 

  BEGIN
  IF NEW.SALARY < 0 or NEW.SALARY > 75000 THEN
  SET NEW.AGE = NULL;
  END IF;
  END//
  DELIMITER;

INSERT INTO `staff` (SALARY) VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO `staff` (SALARY) VALUES (75001);
INSERT INTO `staff` (SALARY) VALUES (75000);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `RHODES`, `M`, `LION`, `2010`, `SD20 52RF`, `10-DEC-1985`, `MANAGER`, `74999`, `rhodes@abbey.ac`,);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `HEINZE`, `F`, `CUB`, `2009`, `WC1 4RF`, `10-DEC-1985`, `SUPERVISOR`, `71999`, `heinze@abbey.ac`,);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `BARNES`, `F`, `FOX`, `2010`, `DD4 5VB`, `10-DEC-1985`, `ADMINISTRATOR`, `34999`, `barnes@abbey.ac`,);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `COLE`, `F`, `TIGER`, `2010`, `NT34 5TG`, `10-DEC-1985`, `CLERK`, `22999`, `cole@abbey.ac`,);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `LUPIRE`, `M`, `LION`, `2010`, `E4 2EE`, `10-DEC-1985`, `CARE TAKER`, `14999`, `lupire@abbey.ac`,);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `WILSHIRE`, `F`, `TIGER`, `2010`, `WE3 8CV`, `10-DEC-1985`, `SECRETARY`, `74999`, `wilshire@abbey.ac`,);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `WALDON`, `M`, `FOX`, `2010`, `AS1 2DF`, `10-DEC-1985`, `ACCOUNTANT`, `74999`, `waldon@abbey.ac`,);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `KNIGHT`, `F`, `LION`, `2010`, `XC23 1WA`, `10-DEC-1985`, `ADMINISTRATOR`, `34999`, `knight@abbey.ac`,);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `GRANT`, `M`, `TIGER`, `2010`, `ED2 5GB`, `10-DEC-1985`, `SUPERVISOR`, `71999`, `grant@abbey.ac`,);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`0010`, `RAY`, `M`, `CUB`, `2010`, `SS0 9ST`, `10-DEC-1985`, `ADMINISTRATOR`, `34999`, `ray@abbey.ac`,);
```

Comment: You've got a few extra comma's.   "   `EMAIL` VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL default '',"  it's the last line in your table create...remove the comma.  You actually do this in most of your table creates.   Side note :   `END_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'  --what is the point of setting it to 0000-00-00 and not allowing nulls?   Null dates will be easier to handle than a default of 0000-00-00

Comment: INSERT INTO `staff` (SALARY) VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO `staff` (SALARY) VALUES (75001);
INSERT INTO `staff` (SALARY) VALUES (75000);

Not sure if I get those entries

Comment: ' and ` is badly confused

Answer (score 2):

What a mess. You're using opening/closing quotes for some values, backticks for others, and a mismatch of backticks and/or quotes.

```
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (`01', '001', ‘GRASS’, ‘LIAM’, ‘20-JUL-1992’,‘M’,'5 BROWN LANE','SS8 4FG','lgrass@gmail.com', `07458914578', );
```

Notice this part:

```
`07458914578'
```

That's a mismatch. Also don't use backticks to write strings or values. Those are to specify column, database, and table names. Also at the end you have a comma indicating another value, but you leave nothing there. It should be `NULL` or `''`.

To be safe, all values that you insert should be only single non-directional quotation marks: `'`

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Here are some things that I notice:

- The declarations for keys go after the definition of the columns.
- The unique key constraint has no comma after it.
- The final column declaration in each table does have a comma, which is not correct.
- The code mixes backticks and single quotes in the declarations of the values.

You may have other errors as well.

You should start with the `students` table and get that to work.  Then, run the inserts into the table.  Then go to the next table.  An incremental approach is how you fix these types of coding problems.

Answer (score 1):

Not able to comment yet, here you go:

First of all, how did you come up with this query? I'm seeing many quotation marks(`) that SQL will get confused. I'll suggest using this **'** all the time. **edited**

Second, Your Table names, you do not have to use quotation marks. I'd guess if you fix all your quotation marks first, it will kill a huge deal of errors.

Comment: The backtick is the escape character for MySQL and is quite important to the language.

Comment: But if you're concise on what you're doing, I don't see a reason of using backticks that much

Comment: Your answer says that "SQL will not recognize [them]".  This is simply incorrect.  Although I agree that their use should be minimized, the proper use of backticks has nothing to do solving the OP's problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
UNIQUE KEY (`TENANT_ID`),
```

You need that comma there.

Edit: I stuck it through [this](http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) and it said the SQL was fine after simply adding the comma, but looking closer now there are loads of other problems that other people already mentioned.